# how to delete files owned by Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ftp, cms, attributes

I've installed a CMS on a shared host running Apache, now when I try to delete the root directory, some sub-directories are left with a "Permission denied" error and I can't change their attributes.

the best explanation I've got is that the CMS installer has placed the files and has assigned its ownership to the Apache server instead of my user name.

so how to delete those directories ?

Comment: Which CMS are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your CMS was written in PHP (as is often the case in shared hosting), you could install [a PHP filemanager](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/), invoke that using a browser and then inspect the files/directories.

If the CMS installer indeed changed the permissions, your filemanager should now be able to do that too.